# Every closed $C^1$ curve in $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is the boundary of some $C^1$ 2-surface $\Sigma \subset \mathbb R^3 \setminus \{ 0 \}$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

How can I prove it?

This problem looks similar to [Plateau's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau%27s_problem) - but it is much more specific. I believe there exists some elementary proof.

(Proving this will help me apply Stokes' theorem to another problem)

thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have a proof that works in some cases (I hope). Assume $\Gamma$ is a such a curve:

- Calculate the center of mass for the curve.
- Translate the curve by its center of mass.
- Define $\Sigma'=\cup_{0 \leq \lambda \leq 1} \lambda \Gamma$, where $\lambda \Gamma=\{   \lambda p:p \in \Gamma\}$
- $\Sigma$ will be $\Sigma'$ translated backwards by the center of mass.

Comment: What smoothness requirement are you placing on $\Sigma$?

Comment: $C^1$ as well, sorry. I also added that $\Gamma$ should be closed.

Comment: You can only expect an immersed surface, not an embedded surface. To see this, consider e.g. the case where the curve is a trefoil knot in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your goal is to apply Stokes' theorem, you need an **orientable** surface. The orientability makes the problem tricky, which is why it took until 1930 to sort it out. Such a surface indeed exists for any smooth $\Gamma$; it is called a *Seifert surface* of $\Gamma$ and can be obtained using [Seifert's algorithm](http://www.sgwater.org/math/knots/). This page has a schematic drawing of a Seifert surface of the trefoil knot; more detailed images can be found with a Google search; e.g., [Visualization of Seifert surfaces](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/vanwijk.pdf).

Your candidate for $\Sigma'$ is not a smooth surface unless $\Gamma$ is a planar curve (look at what happens at the center of mass). It may have self-intersections issues too.

Comment: What do you mean by smooth? $C^1$ or $C^\infty$?