# Closed curves, homotopy and boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, vector-analysis, homotopy-theory, differential-forms

Let $E$ be a path-connected subset of $\mathbb{R^3}$, and $\gamma$ a closed curve in $E$ (not necessarily simple). If I know that $\gamma$ is homotopic to a point trough a closed homotopy inside $E$, is $\gamma$ the boundary of a $2$-manifold contained in $E$?

Intuition seems to be so. Surely, I'm not counting for some pathological cases that I should be (i.e., when $E$ is a line, it can't contain a 2-manifold, right?). But the image of the homotopy is a candidate for such a region, if I can only guarantee that exists an homotopy whose boundary will be exactly $\gamma$ (which seems reasonable, for it informally works on all the well-behaved regions I could think of). The point is to make such argument work:

> Let $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ be two closed homotopic curves in $E$, and let $\omega$ be a closed $1$-form in $E$. Then:
>   $$\int_{\gamma_1} \omega = \int_{\gamma_2} \omega$$
>   PROOF: If $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are homotopic, then $\gamma_1 - \gamma_2$ is homotopic to a point. It is then the boundary of a surface $M$ on $E$: $\partial M = \gamma_1 - \gamma_2$. Applying the Stokes' theorem gives:
>   $$\int_{\gamma_1 - \gamma_2} \omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega = \int_{M} d\omega = \int_M 0 = 0$$
>   By additivity of the integral sign, we have:
>   $$\int_{\gamma_1 - \gamma_2} \omega = \int_{\gamma_1} \omega - \int_{\gamma_2} \omega$$ 
>   Combining both gives the result.

I found those related questions: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836025/let-gamma-1-gamma-2-i-to-m-two-homotopic-curves-m-a-c-infty-mani) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339128/every-closed-c1-curve-in-mathbb-r3-setminus-0-is-the-boundary-of-s). Seems that I need to require $E$ to be open. It would exclude the line example in this case, but I would need to account for all the cases when $E$ isn't open (though I think it works if I separate it in interior and boundary points).

Comment: I wonder whether you might want to reformulate your question, because, keeping in mind that a closed curve in $E$ is nothing more nor less than a function $\gamma : S^1 \to E$ (which in keeping with your question and tags I will assume to be differentiable), this can fail for the simple reason that $\gamma$ is not injective. For example, the image of $\gamma$ can be a figure 8, with $\gamma$ defined by going once around one circle of the 8 and then once around the other circle of the 8.

Comment: @LeeMosher can't the figure 8 be the boundary of any 2-manifold? If one glues two half-spheres at a tangent point, like two bowls touching each other, it's boundary won't be a figure 8? Sure, there can be orientation problems, I'm not sure if they work out. But if one could collapse each of the circles in the figure 8 to the middle point it would become a surface homeomorphic to the one I described, wouldn't it?

Comment: The surface you described isn't a manifold-it's singular at the point of gluing, since you seem to require the point of tangency to be along the boundary.

Comment: Generally, the "proof" you've included is rather incomplete. One has to assume the curves are smooth and disjoint and that the homotopy between them is smooth, which can always be arranged by slight deformations, but complicates the proof significantly.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I see. I'm working this for a challenge in my introductory course in vector calculus, so I was hoping it could be pierced together without it getting too technical on the topology part. Thanks!

Comment: It's a little unclear still exactly what you're trying to do-if you tell us it'd be easier to be more helpful.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I'm trying to show, using Stokes' theorem, that the integral of a closed $1$-form over a loop in a path-connected domain is invariant under homotopy of the loop. So, if $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are homotopic loops on the domain (homotopic trough a closed homotopy fully contained in the domain), then $\int_{\gamma_1} \omega = \int_{\gamma_2} \omega$ for any closed $1$-form $\omega$. After thinking for a while, it maybe possible using the homotopy itself as a pullback from the domain to the plane.